# YAML could not be successfully parsed in Rstudio knitr

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I am facing a problem with `knitr` in `RStudio`. All of a sudden it stopped running, even `knitr` settings are not working showing me this message:

> The YAML front matter in this document could not be successfully parsed.
>   This parse error needs to be resolved before format options can be edited.

The code I am running is this simple one:

````
---
output:
  word_document:default
---
```{r}
Weight <- c(60,72, 57, 90, 95, 72)
Height <- c(1.75, 1.80, 1.65, 1.90, 1.74, 1.91)
BMI <- Weight/Height^2
BMI
```
````

Could you please someone help me ?

Comment: Windows XP, but till now it worked with no problem and I reinstalled RStudio.

Comment: What is the `:default` specifying/trying to accomplish?  I don't use that feature much, but the script builds without the `:default` so I wonder if that part of your specification is in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :default probably ins't needed (It's a default after all), but I believe the reason it won't knit as written is that in the yaml front matter there needs to be a linebreak between `word_document:` and `default`

---

````
output:
word_document:
    default
---
```{r}
Weight <- c(60,72, 57, 90, 95, 72)
Height <- c(1.75, 1.80, 1.65, 1.90, 1.74, 1.91)
BMI <- Weight/Height^2
BMI
```
````

Comment: Both user5219763 and rpierce are right. The default caused the problem. Tnx a lot both of you !!!